# Using a conditional UPDATE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have an `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Employee
 WHERE age = CASE 
 WHEN (age < 20) THEN age=15
 WHEN (age > 20) THEN age= 20
```

Is this not possible in SQL Server / MySQL? I do not want to use the *stored procedures* or other things.

Suggest me a suitable way around this problem.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET age =
CASE WHEN AGE < 20 THEN 15
ELSE 20 END
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works good. I am working with it on MS SQL Server and MySQL Server too. `UPDATE testingtable
SET dob = 
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ADDDATE(dob, INTERVAL -2 day)) > 1 THEN ADDDATE(dob,INTERVAL -2 DAY)
ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP END
WHERE username='bob';`. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If looking to leave value if does not meet condition then set the value to the fieldname. For example above the `ELSE 20 END` would be `ELSE age END`

Answer (score 36):

You can use a case statement in an update as follows...

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Age = CASE WHEN (age < 20) THEN 15
              ELSE 20 END
```

Comment: ha, we must have just crossed paths typing out answers -- i didn't see any others when i submit:-D

Comment: i like how the only different from op's code and yours is the update instead of select and you added an else clause

Comment: and made the assignment a CASE instead having it in the where!

Comment: @EBarr - the reason you didn't see any other answers when you submitted is because you were first...