# sql server 2008, need help to write conditional update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple update statment.

```
Update tbABC
Set salary = 1000, name = 'mike'
Where Id = 1
```

I need to add a condition when update salary, if salary = 0, then change to 1000, otherwise salary will not change.

I did my research, and found a similar question.
[using a conditional update statement in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097815/using-a-conditional-update-statement-in-sql)

```
Update tbABC
Set salary = CASE WHEN (salary = 0) then 1000 ELSE ??????? END, 
    name = 'mike'
Where Id = 1
```

I got stuck on that ???? part.  now sure what to put there to make it salary = salary.

Comment: You already worked it out, but you didn't realise it.  Just put `salary` in there.  It will then update the value to the same value as it was before.  *(As you said, `salary = salary`.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless absolutely necessary, I'd probably prefer using the WHERE clause rather than a complicated CASE function. Simplifying, this would give:

```
update tbABC set salary=1000, name='mike'   -- using condition for both field updates
where Id=1 and salary=0;
```

Or preserving the exact logic over the transaction:

```
update tbABC set salary=1000      -- by ID & only if second condition met
where Id=1 and salary=0;

update tbABC set name='mike'      -- by ID.
where Id=1;
```

I don't really believe there's a real-world case for updating Employee's name unconditionally, but having some condition on his Salary update.

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
Update tbABC
Set salary = CASE WHEN (salary = 0) then 1000 ELSE salary END, 
name = 'mike'
Where Id = 1
```