# SQL UPDATE using an IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, sql-update

I have a table that has a unique identifier of "name" and two fields that are both Boolean statements. The two fields are titled "sentbirth" and "senthire".

What I am trying to do is to see if the value is already true for senthire or sentbirth. If so I want to leave it as true. But if it is false then I want it to update with the @SentBirth or @SentHire value that is being produced from my web application.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT [name],[sentbirth],[senthire]
FROM [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser]
WHERE name = @Name

IF [sentbirth] = '1'
    BEGIN
    UPDATE [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser]
        SET [sentbirth] = '1'
    END 
 ELSE
    BEGIN
     UPDATE [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser]
        SET [sentbirth] = @SentBirth
    END

IF [senthire] = '1'
    BEGIN
    UPDATE [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser]
        SET [senthire] = '1'
    END
 ELSE
    BEGIN
     UPDATE [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser]
        SET [senthire] = @SentHire
    END
```

With this code as is I am receiving the error message that 'sentbirth' and 'senthire' are invalid column names.

How do I write this code properly in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

**Answer to this question is:**

```
UPDATE cu SET
  [sentbirth] = CASE WHEN cu.[sentbirth] = '1' THEN cu.[sentbirth] ELSE @SentBirth END,
  [senthire] = CASE WHEN cu.[senthire] = '1' THEN cu.[senthire] ELSE @SentHire END
FROM [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser] cu
WHERE cu.name = @name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using a conditional update statement in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097815/using-a-conditional-update-statement-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check and keep old or update with new, same for other fields:

```
UPDATE cu SET
  [sentbirth] = CASE WHEN cu.[sentbirth] = '1' THEN cu.[sentbirth] ELSE @sentbirth END,
  ...
FROM [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser] cu
WHERE cu.name = @name
```

Comment: I tried your code as:
`UPDATE cu SET
  [sentbirth] = CASE WHEN cu.[sentbirth] = '1' THEN cu.[sentbirth] ELSE @SentBirth END,
  [senthire] = CASE WHEN cu.[senthire] = '1' THEN cu.[senthire] ELSE @SentHire END,
FROM [CCRAuction].[dbo].[cardsUser] cu
WHERE cu.name = @name`
But I received the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Comment: @Dominick, remove last comma before `FROM`