# SQL - If Else Update Script Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to create an If Else Update Script.  This is what I have put together so far:

```
IF (SELECT [FileType1] 
    FROM Document 
    WHERE ([FileType1] LIKE 'E-mail' OR [FileType1] LIKE 'outlook'))

    UPDATE Document
    SET [FilePath] = [Full Path]

ELSE ((SELECT [FileType1] 
       FROM Document 
       WHERE ([FileType1] NOT LIKE 'E-mail' OR [FileType1] NOT LIKE 'outlook'))

    UPDATE Document
    SET [Path] = [Full Path]
```

What I am I doing wrong? Basically, if E-mail or outlook is found in one statement, I want the **filepath** column to equal the full path column.

If non-E-mails are found, I want the **path** column equal to the full path column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using a conditional update statement in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097815/using-a-conditional-update-statement-in-sql)

Comment: not sure why you need `IF ELSE` here; what is preventing you to write conditions on `UPDATE`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement while defaulting the `ELSE` condition to itself:

```
Update  Document
Set     FilePath =  Case When FileType1 In ('E-mail', 'Outlook')
                        Then [Full Path]
                        Else FilePath
                    End,
        [Path]   =  Case When FileType1 Not In ('E-mail', 'Outlook') 
                        Then [Full Path]
                        Else [Path]
                    End
```

I've also removed the `LIKE` statements (since you're only using them for equality), and removed the `OR` statements in preference of an `IN` and `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can simplify and shorten Siyual's suggestion to just using `[iif]`, which is relatively new, i.e. introduced with SQL Server 2012.

```
update d
set FilePath = iif(FileType1 in ('E-Mail', 'Outlook'), FullPath, FilePath),
    Path = iif(FileType1 not in ('E-Mail', 'Outlook'), FullPath, Path)
from Document d;
```

Hopes this help.

Comment: IIF in SQL? I was a bit surprised, but then I read in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396