# Update multiple rows in sequelize with different conditions

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to perform an update command with sequelize on rows in a postgres database. I need to be able to update multiple rows that have different conditions with the same value.

For example, assume I have a user table that contains the following fields:

- ID
- First Name
- Last Name
- Gender
- Location
- createdAt

Assume, I have 4 records in this table, I want to update records with ID - 1 and 4 with a new location say Nigeria.

Something like this: `SET field1 = 'foo' WHERE id = 1, SET field1 = 'bar' WHERE id = 2`

How can I achieve that with sequelize?

Comment: Does any DBMS support that SQL syntax? Maybe what you want is `CASE WHEN` as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097815/using-a-conditional-update-statement-in-sql ? That's asked more specifically at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396796/how-to-use-case-when-expression-in-sequelize but no one was able to provide a non-literal approach so far.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can update multiple record at a time , but same updates for all records 
, if you want to make different updates for different conditons then you have to run that multiple time

**Example :**

This will update `fields1` to foo , where `id` is 1 or 4

```
let ids = [1,4];
Your_model.update({ field1 : 'foo' },{ where : { id : ids }});
```

This will update `field1` to foo if `id` is 1 , and `field1` to bar if `id` is 4

```
Your_model.update({ field1 : 'foo' },{ where : { id : 1 }});
Your_model.update({ field1 : 'bar' },{ where : { id : 4 }});
```

Hope this will clear all your doubts.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: @proton , Glad to know, Thanks , Happy Coding BTW.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Is there some way we can do this with a single update query.

Answer (score 21):

You can update multiple rows following your conditions, and to do that the operators are very helpful.

Look here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html (operators)

```
const { Op } = Sequelize;
DisplayMedia.update(
    {
        field: 'bar'
    },
    {
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.in]: [1, 10, 15, ..]   // this will update all the records 
            }                           // with an id from the list
        }
    }
)
```

There is all kinds of operators, including the range operators, or like operator ...etc

Also one of the important questions when it come to update, is how to update all rows?

Not including `where` results in an error "**Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to update**".

The answer is in the code bellow: provide a `where` with an **empty object**.

```
await DisplayMediaSequence.update({
    default: false
}, {
    where: {}, // <-- here
    transaction
});
await DisplayMediaSequence.update({ 
    default: true     <-- after all turned to false, we now set the new default. (that to show a practical expample) -->
}, {
    where: {
        id
    },
    transaction
});
```

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer, it directly solves the question asked. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

we planning to save different values for same fields in multiple row there is a possible for getting all field values are same in database.
using for loop

```
const {idArray,group_id} = params;

for(const item of idArray){

    const response = await Your_model.findOne({ where:{group_id,user_id:null}, order: [['id', 'DESC']] });

    await response.update({user_id:item});
}
```